# Adobe Air with native android access

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, adobe, native

I have been trying to follow James Ward's instructions in order to access native apis with adobe air. No matter how many times i re read his steps, I cant follow them properly.

I didn't use the eclipse source files offered on his site as I already have an android app using netbeans which accesses and sets up communication with another device via bluetooth.

I also have a previously created air app which read/writes to a socket, displays ui and reponds to button presses.

If i could get the bluetooth-connected socket created in the native app, pass this to the air app and allow the bluetooth communication to be utilised in air it would be a great satisfaction for me as i have been at this for days.

Is this possible and if so can someone help me, i have managed to extract the air apk, get the dex files, but what next??

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You currently cannot access native APIs from Air, but it is currently in the works.

Comment: IS it Still under Work?What is the current Status?

Comment: With the version of Air, you can create Native Extensions; native code that Air can call that can make call to the native API.  Look it up :)

Comment: Which AIR version for Android? 3.5?